# Proving coarser and finer topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I'm relatively new in studying topology so please bear with me. We were given this as an exercise:

> Suppose $X$ is a non-empty set and $A ⊆ X$. Let $M$ and $P$ be topologies of $X$, and $M$ is coarser than $P$. Prove that the closure of $P$ ($Cl_P$)  is a subset of the closure of $M$ ($Cl_M$), $Cl_P ⊆ Cl_M$.

My attempt so far:

> $Cl_M$ and $Cl_P$, by definition of closure, are closed sets that contains the intersection of all closed supersets of $A$. Since $M$ is coarser than $P$, then every closed subset in $M$ must also be closed in $P$.

I'm stuck at this point. I'm not sure what should follow or if my attempt is on the right track. Any help/hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're well on track. All that remains is to note that the closure in $M$ will be an intersection of some sets. The closure in $P$ will be an intersection of all those sets and also possibly more sets on top of that. An intersection over more sets can only become smaller.

Comment: Just a clarification. So what I have to show next is that a set is not in the closure in P but is in the closure in M, since topology M is coarser than P?

Comment: @Kiel The closure in $P$ and in $M$ could be equal (consider, for instance, the closure of the whole space). So you don't have to show that the closure in $M$ is strictly larger. But yes, formally you will have to take an arbitrary point in the $P$-closure, and show that it is also included in the $M$-closure. This is probably most directly done by reasoning about what it means for a point to be in an intersection.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Kiel A less direct, but perhaps shorter and more elegant way is to note that because $M$ is coarser than $P$, the $M$-closure is closed in $P$, and it is therefore one of the sets that the $P$-closure is an intersection of. And any set contains any intersection where it is itself one of the intersected sets.

Answer (score 0):

You can also generalize the result(remove context of topology on set). **Claim:** If $A\subseteq B$, then $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{B}$. **Proof:** let $x\in \overline{A}$. So $\forall V\in \mathcal{N}_x$, $V\cap A\neq \emptyset$. Note $A\subseteq B \Rightarrow A\cap V \subseteq B\cap V$. So $V\cap B \neq \emptyset$. Thus $ \forall V\in \mathcal{N}_x$, $V\cap B\neq \emptyset$. Hence $x\in \overline{B}$.

I used different(from what you are using) equivalent definition of closure. “Application”: We use this result in exercise 3(b) and 5, section 28 of Munkres topology.